# Reuse item inside a row when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, collections, uicollectionreusableview

I have **collectionView** inside **tableView**. **collectionView** need to horizontal scroll image, **tableView** for vertical scroll posts. When I had 3 **rows** I had no problems, but when i create 4 **rows** i have a problem with scrolling **items** inside rows. If I start scrolling on 4 **row**, scrolling is repeated on **row** 1 and the same thing if i start scrolling on 1 **row** scrolling is repeating on **row** 4.

What could be the problem and how to solve it? May be

Can check .gif file. I start on 1 **row** on name "**Oko**" and if i scrolling down on 4 **row** and scroll right **collectionCell** and **return** on 1 **row** i see next image name "City", but there must be name "**Oko**"

My code:

**ViewController:**

```
class PhotoStudiosViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var theStudios: [Studio] = [] 
    var filteredStudios: [Studio] = [] 

    var studiosRef: DatabaseReference!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 475
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        studiosRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "PhotoStudios1")

        studiosRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            for imageSnap in snapshot.children {

                let studioObj = Studio(snapshot: imageSnap as! DataSnapshot)

                self.theStudios.append(studioObj)

            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        })

    }
    // MARK: - TableView
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {

            return filteredStudios.count

        }

        return theStudios.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoStudiosTableViewCell

        cell.currentPageNumber.text = "1/\(theStudios[indexPath.row].halls.count)"

        if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != nil {
            cell.theHalls = filteredStudios[indexPath.row].halls
        } else {
            cell.theHalls = theStudios[indexPath.row].halls
        }

        cell.nameLabel.text = theStudios[indexPath.row].studioName

        cell.addressLabel.text = theStudios[indexPath.row].studioAddress

        cell.logoLabel.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: theStudios[indexPath.row].studioLogo))

        cell.didSelectAction = {

            (innerPath) in

            self.showDetailsView(indexPath, cellPath: innerPath)

        }

        return cell

    }
```

**TableViewCell:**

```
class PhotoStudiosTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UIScrollViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var logoLabel: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var addressLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var currentPageNumber: UILabel!

    var didSelectAction: ((IndexPath) -> ())?

    var theHalls: [Hall] = [] {
        didSet {
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    var lastContentOffset = CGPoint.zero 

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        resetCollectionView()

    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        currentPageNumber.layer.zPosition = 2
        currentPageNumber.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        currentPageNumber.clipsToBounds = true    

    }

    func resetCollectionView() {
        guard !theHalls.isEmpty else { return }
        theHalls = []
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    // MARK: - CollectionView
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return theHalls.count

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoStudiosCollectionViewCell2

        cell.hallName.text = theHalls[indexPath.item].hallName

        cell.priceLabel.text = theHalls[indexPath.item].hallPrice

        cell.metrslabel.text = theHalls[indexPath.item].hallMetrs

        cell.photoStudioImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: theHalls[indexPath.item].hallImage))

        return cell

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        didSelectAction?(indexPath)

    }

}
```

[image: git image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reusing the collection views in your cells, which is correct, but that means the contentOffset is also left from whatever was scrolled to previously when a cell is reused. It should be sufficient to just reset the contentOffset in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` when you are setting up your cell by doing something like:

```
cell.collectionView.contentOffset = .zero
```

One thing worth mentioning is that I do see you have a property called `lastContentOffset` in your cells that doesn't do anything yet and I suspect you are going to try to use that to persist the offset for a given cell when it scrolls out of view so that you can set it again when it comes back into view (rather than always resetting).

If you are going to do that, having the property in the cell won't work. You'll need to have a list of offsets for each cell stored alongside your data models in the containing view controller. Then you might save the offset for a given cell in `didEndDisplayingCell` and setting it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` instead of `.zero` as I did above.

Comment: it helped me `cell.collectionView.contentOffset = .zero`. Big thanks, the second day trying to solve this problem. About other I will think do I need it.